# How can you install specific version of Chromium or Chrome on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome, browser

I cannot find anything for - how to install specific version of Chromium/Chrome on Linux Ubuntu.

I searched in apt-get PM and from SNAP. For example we have only this one:

```
apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

```
snap install chromium-browser
```

But there is no version flag or something like where you can set a specific version. Anyone some ideas ?

Comment: It's not a recommended method, but you can download Chromium binaries directly from [chromium.org](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/#not-as-easy-steps).

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt-get` to install outdated versions will probably not work – dependencies will have moved on.

snap or flatpak would stand a better chance; for the snap case, try following the "channel" approach [detailed here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1371602) to select a specific release series of chromium. (is `chromium-browser` really the name in the snap store? I haven't checked!)